# Is it sufficient to prove that $| f(x,y) – L | = 0 $ so that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y) =L$ is true?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, absolute-value

Im trying to proove the following limit by the squeeze theorem:

$$  \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0 $$

I've seen **all** the related questions, and I can't understand the validity of applying absolute value as it follows:

Of course we have that:  $|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|≥0$ , and also
$ |\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|=  \frac{|x|\cdot |y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} ≤                    \frac{|x|\cdot |y|}{\sqrt{y^2}} = \frac{|x|\cdot |y|}{|y|}=|x|$, Therfore, by the squeeze theorem:

$$ 0≤|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|≤|x|  $$
$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}  0≤\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}  |\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|≤\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} |x|  $$
$$ 0≤\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}  |\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|≤0  $$

So finally that should be sufficient to prove that the distance $| f(x,y) – L | = 0 $ and therefore, that should be enough to say that:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0$$

Then my question is: is this valid? Or am I committing a mathematical atrocity.  Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: You don't mean $|f(x,y)-L|=0$. You are not writing the squeeze principle correctly. If $f(x)\le g(x)\le h(x)$ and $f(x),h(x)\to L$, then $\lim g(x)=L$. Part of this statement is the fact that the limit exists. If you had $0\le g(x)\le 1$, you might be tempted to write $0\le \lim g(x)\le 1$, which is correct *only if* the limit is known to exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't really know if $y = 0$ or not. See, $(x,y)$ needs to not be $(0,0)$ when we're taking the limit but that just means that either $x \neq 0$ or $y \neq 0$. If you do it the way that you did, then you're basically stopping yourself from approaching the origin through any path that goes arbitrarily through the $x$-axis.

Instead, it's probably much better for you to recognize that:
$$|x| \cdot |y| \leq \frac{|x|^2+|y|^2}{2} = \frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$$
Then:
$$\frac{|x|\cdot|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
As $(x,y) \to (0,0)$, the right-hand side goes to $0$ without any issues and you obtain the result that you want via the Squeeze Theorem.

**Edit:**

Right, so what I meant by my paragraph above is the way you reached your derivation of:
$$\frac{|x|\cdot|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leq |x|$$
There, you just removed the $x^2$ in the denominator. That's going to cause you problems. You could get to the above by recognizing that:
$$\frac{|x|\cdot|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leq \frac{|x|\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = |x|$$
Over here, you don't encounter any problems.

Comment: I don't understand your first paragraph. The inequality $\frac{|x||y|}{\sqrt{x^2+ y^2}}\le |x|$ is true for all $(x, y)\neq (0,0)$.

Comment: Look at the way that OP got to that, though. They did it by:

$$\frac{|x| \cdot |y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leq \frac{|x| \cdot |y|}{|y|}= |x|$$

which is going to cause problems.

Comment: But $\left|\frac y{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right|\le 1$ is correct (whenever the denominator is positive) and this is a wonderful technique to learn to use.

Comment: Sure, I didn't say that you shouldn't use that technique at all, I just pointed out that the specific way in which OP did it doesn't really work out all that well. I, then, proceeded to give an alternative approach.

Comment: Why is there a downvote?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote... first of all, thank you for your wonderful help and answers. I understand your edited part and I agree. From that, a more fundamental question arises and I would be really thankful for your guidance:

Even if we prove the inequity by the squeeze theorem $0≤\frac{|x|\cdot |y|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} ≤ |x|$... Why does that mean that the original limit, which has no absolute value, is also zero? Perhaps my lack of knowledge is due to the mathematical principles behind this problem. In other words, I have problems understanding the role of the absolute value mmmhh..